# How can I debug Objects in Pebble.js?

Tags: javascript, logging, pebble-js

I'm fetching via ajax

```
ajax(
    {
        url: ...,
        type: 'json'
    },
    function(data) {
        // Success!
        console.log(data);
    },
    function(error) {
        // Failure!
    }
)
```

And I'm getting

```
[HANDY] pebble-app.js:?: [object Object]
```

If I know what attributes to look for, I can access them by `data.key`. But how about objects with unknown attributes or if I simply need deep debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) so you can see the values of your object as a JSON string in the [app log](http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/pebble-apps/debugging/debugging-guide/):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Lot's of [Pebble.js examples](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/pebblejs/) use that to debug.